# Kernel 2.6.38-10 and 2.6.38-11 unable to boot in AHCI mode

Tags: 11.04, boot, kernel, grub2, sata

I switched in my BIOS (on an old Gigabyte GA-MA74GM-S2H, rev. 1.1, Bios F1) the SATA settings from "Native IDE" to "AHCI" and was surprised that GRUB2 was not able to boot my kernel anymore. It stated:

```
Cannot read the Linux header
```

I was running the latest Natty kernel 2.6.38-11 / 32bit PAE.

Guessing a problem with GRUB2 and AHCI I was much more confused as I was able to load older kernel version including 2.6.38-9, but not -10 anymore.
So I dumped -10 and -11 and re-installed kernel 2.6.38-11 (generic and pae) with the same result but a different error message (*could not load file*).
Changing the SATA settings back to "Native IDE" mode, everything works OK.

Anyone observed this too and has any suggestions?

The reason I want to run in AHCI is because I want to install a SSD drive in near future, running it in AHCI for better performance and as suggested by the vendor (OCZ).

Edit:

here's a part of my grub.cfg. Config for Kernel 2.6.38-11, not running:

```
 menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 2.6.38-11-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 14611dce-f4ab-498d-b1a1-609ed9f17da2
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-generic-pae root=UUID=14611dce-f4ab-498d-b1a1-609ed9f17da2 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-11-generic-pae
 }
```

Running 2.6.38-9 configuration:

```
 menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 2.6.38-9-generic-pae' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 14611dce-f4ab-498d-b1a1-609ed9f17da2
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-9-generic-pae root=UUID=14611dce-f4ab-498d-b1a1-609ed9f17da2 ro   quiet splash vt.handoff=7
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-9-generic-pae
 }
```

Maybe I'm blind but I don't see any difference in the important parts.

Here the blkid output:

```
 halil@KlingonWarrior:~$ sudo blkid -c /dev/null
 /dev/sda1: UUID="14611dce-f4ab-498d-b1a1-609ed9f17da2" TYPE="ext4" 
 /dev/sda5: UUID="14ebd487-ff28-4678-831b-d94dd9df4f60" TYPE="swap" 
 /dev/sdb1: LABEL="HOMETREK" UUID="B044B71044B6D7F4" TYPE="ntfs"
```

And, as written, both configurations run in "Native IDE" mode.

BTW, the Re-Intstall of the -11 kernel was done in AHCI mode.

EDIT2:

Ok, here the fdisk output:

```
 halil@KlingonWarrior:~$ sudo fdisk -lu

 Platte /dev/sda: 163.9 GByte, 163928604672 Byte
 255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 19929 Zylinder, zusammen 320173056 Sektoren
 Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0x477d477c

    Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
 /dev/sda1   *          63   308094569   154047253+  83  Linux
 /dev/sda2       308094570   320159384     6032407+   5  Erweiterte
 /dev/sda5       308094633   320159384     6032376   82  Linux Swap / Solaris

 Platte /dev/sdb: 500.1 GByte, 500107862016 Byte
 255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 60801 Zylinder, zusammen 976773168 Sektoren
 Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0x74720d9c

    Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
 /dev/sdb1   *          63   976768064   488384001    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

Sorry 4 the german output.... More info needed?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the records:

I've flashed the mainboard with the latest and greatest BIOS (F4 beta) and now the boot problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

First add the output of `sudo fdisk -lu` to your question.  Then try to boot in AHCI mode and when you get to the grub menu, press `c` to go to the command line.  Enter `ls -l` for a detailed listing of your drives as grub sees them, and add that information as well.  Repeat that with the controller in IDE mode and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Done already, there is no difference. As I've stated, I was able to boot into the older Kernel versions. I don't see any difference in the grub.cfg (see above in the edit)

Comment: @che---, please add the exact numbers to your question.  There still may be something fishy on close inspection.

Comment: @che---, how about the `ls -l` output from the grub prompt?

Comment: I've checked this on my Laptop (Dell D830, running 11.04 64b), switched from IDE to AHCI w/o any problem so I assume it's a incompatibility between my MB Controller and the latest Kernels or it's simply a problem in the file system itself.

Comment: @che--- that is exactly the wrong conclusion.  The kernel is just fine; it is the bios, and therefore grub, that has the problem.  That is why I keep asking for the output of `ls -l` in the grub prompt; to see how big the bios thinks the disk is when in ACHI mode.

Comment: any idea how I can write the grub console output into a file system? Don't find anything regarding this in the grub docu. The output is a bit large with 'ls -l'.

Comment: @che--- no, you just either need to use a pen and paper or take a picture.